# Is there any way to get the CSS :not() selector working in IE and Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, css, css-selectors

Anyone know any tricks to use the CSS **`:not()`** selector in IE and Chrome?

e.g. this works in Firefox: `iframe:not(.anifrmclass){}`

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specificity is your friend. Apply your `:not(.anifrmclass)` styles to all `<iframe>`s then override with other values for `<iframe class="anifrmclass">`.

```
iframe {
    /* Styles for all -other- iframes */
    display: none;
}

iframe.anifrmclass {
    /* Override for this class with values other than the above */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that. Thanks, BoltClock!

Comment: When styling list items with something like margin, li:not(:last-child) does not work, and this method is no help. No one wants to add a special class to the end list item.