# css modification (can use ! not)?

Tags: css

I can do .one.two and that targets any element with the class "one" AND the class "two" right?

What if I want to target any element with class "one" but that can't be coupled with "two" ? eg .one !.two or something like that.

Thx all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 includes `:not()`, but it's not yet supported by IE, I think.  Works in recent versions of other browsers:

```
.one:not(.two) {
  //your styles
}
```

Comment: I may try your css3 approach using some jquery (wouldn't be the first time). not preferable, but I'll take it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [:not pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation)

Or use a negation class: [Is there any way to get the CSS :not() selector working in IE and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464234/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-css-not-selector-working-in-ie-and-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

```
.one {background: red;}
.two {background: green;}
.one.two {background: blue;}
```

I don't see why you'd need 'not' there as `.one` would style the same as `.one but not .two`. If you are already using multiple classes, you should be good to go.

Comment: this would have worked, but I'm working with JS gen classes (builds up to 12 sometimes) so using :not is easier than taking the logical approach. thanks for the good answer though!

Comment: Hmm...perhaps expand your question with a larger example so we can get an idea of your ultimate goal. There might be a different way to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to [read about specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

`.one` will select all `class="one"` elements, `.two` will select all `class="two"` elements.

`.one.two` will select all `class="one two"` elements and will override any rules that may have been set for `.one` or `.two` for that element.

The `.one:not(.two)` selector will perform the negation you desire, but it's not cross-browser compatible.

The most cross-browser compatible way of adding a rule like `.one:not(.two)` is to add an override:

```
.one
{
  color: blue;
}

.one.two
{
  color: black;
}
```