# Mixing two css for different nav definitions

Tags: javascript, css, nav

I have 2 css and both of them have specifications for **nav**

What would be the best way to use both of them?

The issue here is the second definition of nav has also a **li** definition that involves an **id** like

`<li id="all">All</li>`

This id I am using on a js.

[I have this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/241/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `:not` operator in CSS and exclude the first nav from second nav css definition.

Add a class to firstNav, and then inside the css use `:not` like so

`nav ul:not(.first)`

**Edit**

Check the fiddle again. Seems like there is another trick to do this, something called a [substring matching](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/) . Note that the order of the css in the fiddle is important. if you flip the definitions of the navs, the css will not work. I haven't tested this in IE 8, but based on what I read, it should work in IE8 as well.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhJXt/)

Comment: Does the crappy IE supports the operator?

Comment: Seems like it does.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464234/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-css-not-selector-working-in-ie-and-chrome

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: SO IE8 and less do not support them